# how to fix aws lightsail ubuntu Internal Server Error?

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services

AWS Lightsail suddenly shows error 500
After checking logs, there was an error `AH10292: Invalid proxy UDS filename (proxy:unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/website.net/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/vhosts/website.net/httpdocs/index.php), referer: https://website.net/`
All of my websites on lightsail are down, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Plesk has a similar report](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4407366133906-Website-on-Plesk-server-suddenly-started-to-show-500-error-AH10292-Invalid-proxy-UDS-filename), too:

> Cause
>
> The issue is related to the latest Apache update, which changed the approach in handling UDS URIs used to proxy connections from Apache to PHP-FPM.

Theirs (which must not mean theirs) solution is to downgrade Apache 2 and put it on hold.

Ubunutu 20.04:

```
# export version="2.4.41-4ubuntu3"; \
  apt-get install apache2=$version apache2-utils="$version" \
    apache2-data=$version apache2-bin="$version"; \
  apt-mark hold apache2
```